# What to do with a QR code from web.whatsapp.com?

Tags: qr-code

I'm trying to run whatsapp web from the PC web browser.

[web.whatsapp.com](https://www.rootupdate.com/whatsapp-web-login/)

[image]

I have no camera to read and process the QR-code generated.

Then I used [this](https://webqr.com/) website to read the image and it gives me the following string:

`1@wQ6XTiEmEYSbopFLeZhyeYpTBuXNkUgS6t21o4BfCpMamxgjpSjnJ1KN,5HnBeFEQlOLz1eUij+0svtffHpSvOvexDJX+nts0TDA=,Gd2eq2kDLGpWQp5rrzRHqw==`

I know that some QR-codes are actually urls, but not this one. Now, how to proceed with this QRCode?

Comment: I have a VirtualBox running android-x86, but still no camera.

Comment: It is designed to require a camera in the phone you're running WhatsApp. There's no workaround.

Comment: As we are here, is there an app to read qr-code images in android without a camera?

Comment: Are you trying to use WhatsApp without a phone? There are [guides with suggestions on how to accomplish that](https://www.techbout.com/whatsapp-without-phone-number-sim-5365/) available on the internet.

Comment: @davidmneedham That's probably the answer the OP needs; not the answer he deserves. [reference](https://www.askmen.com/recess/fun_lists/the-most-memorable-dark-knight-trilogy-quotes/the-hero-gotham-needs.html)

Comment: @jpaugh , if that is the question the OP is trying to answer, it looks like there is a similar question on another StackExchange site: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99889/use-whatsapp-desktop-or-web-without-a-connection-on-my-phone

Comment: @davidmneedham - I don't think the methods in your link can be used for the WebApp: I have previously used this link for a tablet without a SIM and it worked, but it works with the 'phone app, and I don't see how the WebApp, which links to an enabled mobile, can be configured in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the QR reader is a Base 64 string,<sup>1</sup> which can be decoded [here](https://www.base64decode.org/). however, decoding it gives garbage text

```
:]8FnE-a)L6E Kv֎|*Ljl`J7DBSW?_|zR2W{l0ݞi,jVBk4G
```

which means it's probably bit of binary data, in some format that WhatsApp would recognize. This makes sense, because Base64 is often used to encode binary data in a format (such as a QR code) that only allows plain text.

Figuring out more would require you to know about the internal workings of WhatsApp. Actually using it would require feeding this base64 string into WhatsApp in such a way that the app thought this was coming from the QR Reader/Camera. Easier said than done!

<sup>1</sup> Not every base64 string ends with `==`, but having that at the end is a dead giveaway.